# How to get values of jQuery UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to collect the values of jQuery UI Slider from start to end values and show in input text-box.

jQuery code:

```
      $(function () {
          $("#Slider1").slider({

              from: 1000,
              to: 100000,
              step: 500,smooth: true, round: 0, dimension: "&nbsp;RS ", skin: "plastic",                

              slide: function (event, ui) {
                  //$("#lblPrice").text("Price range: Rs " + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
                  var val = $('#Slider1').slider("option", "value");
                  alert(val);
                  $("#PrcRange").val("Price range: Rs " + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
                  alert($("#minval").val(ui.values[0]));
                  $("#minval").val(ui.values[0]);
                  $("#maxval").val(ui.values[1]);
              }
          });
          $("#PrcRange").val("Rs " + $("#Slider1").slider("values", 0) + " - Rs" + $("#Slider1").slider("values", 1));

      });
```

And html:

```
<div class="layout-slider" style="width: 100%">
  Slider <span style="display: inline-block; width: 400px; padding: 0 5px;"><input id="Slider1" type="slider" name="price" value="30000.5;60000" /></span>  in Amount

<div id="slider-range"></div>
    <input id="minval" type="text" />
    <input id="maxval" type="text" />
    <input id="PrcRange" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code you have presently?

Comment: i need to get values to show in input box , slider is working correctly, but can't able to get the amount to show from and to in input box, in minval input box i need to show the starting amount, in max val i need to show ending amount

Comment: Use $('#slider').slider("option", "min")) for min value  and $('#slider').slider("option", "max"))  for max value